# Qt: save entire QScrollArea contents as an image

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to save the contents of a QScrollArea as an image.
Currently, I am doing it this way...

```
QPixmap pixmap(ui->overview->rect().size());
ui->overview->render(&pixmap, QPoint(),QRegion(ui->overview->rect()));

QString saveFilename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Save as", "Choose a filename","PNG(*.png);; TIFF(*.tiff *.tif);; JPEG(*.jpg *.jpeg)");
if(!pixmap.save(saveFilename))
{
    QMessageBox::warning(this, "Error","File could not be saved", QMessageBox::Ok);
}
```

But if the contents exceed one screen (and you need to scroll to see the entire image) and I save that,
the image only shows the part of the screen it's currently on.

How can I save the full contents of the scrollArea so that the image shows the entire thing, and not just a part of it?

Comment: To be clear: ui->overview is the scrollArea I want to save.

Comment: Instead of rendering the scroll area into a `QPixmap`, you should render the scroll area's widget. You can use [QScrollArea::widget()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qscrollarea.html#widget) to get the scroll area's widget.

Answer (score 1):

```
QImage img(ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->size(),QImage::Format::Format_ARGB32);
QPainter painter(&img);
ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->render(&painter);
bool istrue = img.save("/file.jpg");
```

Comment: use scrollareawidget not acrollarea

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.